# Rails NullBoolean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, sqldatatypes

Does Rails have a built-in equivalent to the Django NullBoolean, accepting three values (nil, true, false)? If not, how would you recommend implementing it?

In my case I have a table of `Overrides` and a table of `Objects`. `Objects` can have many `Overrides`. `Overrides` are nearly identical in structure to `Objects`. Before reading the value of an `Object`, I'm pulling its `Overrides`, conditionally picking through them, and then applying those values on top of the `Object`.

Any field of an `Override` that is nil does not apply any changes. This system is working well for me, but I just added a boolean field to `Objects`, so I need to put a nullable boolean on `Overrides`. Django's `NullBoolean` works well in this type of scenario, but I'm having trouble finding a rails equivalent.

Comment: How about defining your own type?

Comment: AR separates nullability and type and assumes that everything can be NULL unless you explicitly say `:null => false`.

Comment: Thanks @mu is too short, that's what I was looking for. I assumed setting booleans to nil got saved as false, like in Django.

Comment: If you post that as an answer I'll accept it instead of my own. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ActiveRecord separates nullability and type in the database. Also, ActiveRecord creates columns as nullable unless you explicitly specify `:null => false` when you create/alter the column. So you should be able to create a standard boolean column:

```
create_table "..." do |t|
  #...
  t.boolean "boolean_column"
end
```

and then assign true/false/nil as needed:

```
o.boolean_column = true  # true
o.boolean_column = false # false
o.boolean_column = nil   # null
```

Comment: Just something to be aware of... predicate methods will return `false`  when column value is `nil`. This should not be an issue, but it can be if `nil` has a different expectation than `false`.

Answer (score -2):

In Ruby, we got `nil`.

For conditional statements, `nil` is interpreted as `false`.

```
1.8.7 :001 > if nil
1.8.7 :002?>   0
1.8.7 :003?>   end
 => nil 
1.8.7 :004 > if false
1.8.7 :005?>   0
1.8.7 :006?>   end
 => nil 
1.8.7 :007 > if true
1.8.7 :008?>   0
1.8.7 :009?>   end
 => 0 
1.8.7 :010 > x = 0
 => 0 
1.8.7 :011 > if nil
1.8.7 :012?>   x = 1
1.8.7 :013?>   end
 => nil 
1.8.7 :014 > x
 => 0 
1.8.7 :015 > if false
1.8.7 :016?>   x = 1
1.8.7 :017?>   end
 => nil 
1.8.7 :018 > if true
1.8.7 :019?>   x = 1
1.8.7 :020?>   end
 => 1 
1.8.7 :021 > x
 => 1 
1.8.7 :022 > if 2 
1.8.7 :023?>   x= 2
1.8.7 :024?>   end
 => 2 
1.8.7 :025 > x
 => 2
```

What's interesting is that if you do non- `nil` value in Ruby, it is interpreted as `true` like you see in the last case.